# Creating a tar file using remove-files and exclude

Tags: tar

I have the following directory structure and files:

```
test:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 db2root1 db2iadm1 4096 Jan 18 16:52 archive
-rw-r--r-- 1 db2root1 db2iadm1   34 Jan 18 16:38 file1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 db2root1 db2iadm1   34 Jan 18 16:38 file2.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 db2root1 db2iadm1 4096 Jan 18 17:04 subdir

test/archive:
total 0

test/subdir:
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 db2root1 db2iadm1 34 Jan 18 16:38 file3.txt
```

Now I want to create a tar file in the directory archive without the directory archive and the file file1.txt with the following command:

```
tar --remove-files --exclude file1.txt --exclude archive -cvzf /test/archive/test.tar.gz /test
```

I put the --exclude and --remove-files options to different places but always get the following error message:

```
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/test/
/test/subdir/
/test/subdir/file3.txt
/test/file2.txt
tar: /test: Cannot rmdir: Directory not empty
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

How can I prevent the error regarding the base directory /test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
( cd /test; tar --remove-files --exclude file1.txt --exclude archive -cvzf archive/test.tar.gz * )
```

The trick is to `cd` into the directory and then `tar *`; the subshell will prevent the `cd` having any effect in the upper-level shell.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use `--remove-files`, which will ["remove files after adding them to the archive"](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar).

You're placing the tarball at `/test/archive/test.tar.gz`, and tarring up `/test/`. The `--remove-files` option is telling `tar` to delete the directory `/test/` at the end, but so long as `tar` is running it will be accessing the file `/test/archive/test.tar.gz`, so you wont be able to delete the directory.

You can either throw out the `--remove-files` option, or place your `tar` in a different directory.